qemu-system-arm respnse: Timer with period zero, disabling ON ubuntu24
This is my first question in overflow, please give me some feedback to the my statement.
I using the qemu and freeRTOS on virtualbox ubuntu 24.04, but received one problem.
using command qemu-system-arm -machine lm3s811evb -kernel gcc/RTOSDemo.bin -s -S -nographic get this response Timer with period zero, disabling. Besides, ctrl+c doesn't stop this process.
Please help me.
enter image description here
Help me find the solution and tell me why. Thank you.

That warning is unimportant; you can ignore it. Your problem will be something unrelated -- probably your guest code is crashing in early startup. Use the gdbstub or QEMU debug logging to debug that. If you use -nographic then ctrl-c not stopping QEMU is expected -- you have asked for a setup where ctrl-c is sent through to the guest. The exit key code is ctrl-A x : see https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/mux-chardev.html

Thank you so much! This information has helped me a lot. I had overlooked the possibility of the guest code crashing. I'll try it on Sunday.
